# Strange behaviour of the ImageList that throws ArgumentException

Tags: .net, imagelist, argumentexception

I'm so confused when I'm using ImageList in .NET. First of all I have a global object (ImageManager) that contains three different ImageLists:

- **`smallImages`** (size: 16x16) - contains 50 images (added from Designer)
- **`largeImages`** (size: 48x48) - contains 0 images
- **`gridImages`** (size: 16x16) - contains 17 images (added from Designer)

ImageManager is initiliazed once on startup. **`gridImages`** is used in Grid control (JanusGridEx) and it's passed by value. In runtime (in Grid control) I'm adding three new images to **`gridImages`**. I was trying to add it in three difference ways:

- First try

> ```
> Dim ImageBuffer As Byte() = CType(DataRow(pColumnImageName), Byte())
> gridImages.Images.Add(imageKey, New Icon(New MemoryStream(ImageBuffer)))
> ```

- Second try

> ```
>  Dim ImageBuffer As Byte() = CType(DataRow(pColumnImageName), Byte())
>  Dim newImage As Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(ImageBuffer))
>  gridImages.Images.Add(newImage)
> ```

- Third try (I think this is the best way - correct me if I'm wrong)

> ```
> Dim ImageBuffer As Byte() = CType(DataRow(pColumnImageName), Byte())
> Using ms As New MemoryStream(ImageBuffer , 0, ImageBuffer.Length)
>       gridImages.Images.Add(imageKey, Image.FromStream(ms))
> End Using
> ```

Now the problem is, when the last image is added to that **`gridImages`** and I want to ie. get the last Image by using imageKey or index `(gridImages.Images(20))` I receive exception: **`System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.`** callstack:

> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
>   at System.Drawing.Bitmap.LockBits(Rectangle rect, ImageLockMode flags, PixelFormat format, BitmapData bitmapData)
>   at System.Drawing.Bitmap.LockBits(Rectangle rect, ImageLockMode flags, PixelFormat format)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ImageList.GetBitmap(Int32 index)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ImageList.ImageCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
>   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.Internal.JNSBB.a(Graphics , Brush , String , Image , Rectangle , ImageHorizontalAlignment , ImageVerticalAlignment , JNSDQ , Font , Boolean , Int32 , ImageList , Boolean )
>   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.EditControls.JNSAQ.a(Graphics , Int32 , Rectangle )
>   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.EditControls.JNSAQ.a(Graphics )
>   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.EditControls.JNSAQ.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at Janus.Windows.GridEX.EditControls.JNSAQ.WndProc(Message& msg)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, >IntPtr lparam)

**First Question:** Why is that? When I create a new instance of Image and even try to save it on a disk it works correctly.

**Second Question:** Before I pass the ImageList by value to the Grid control I create a new instance of ImageList and copy all the images from the ImageList (ImageManager) to that instance (DeepCopy). When I make the DeepCopy and add new Images to the new ImageList it works fine too. Why is that? Why is it working?